# Is this tensorflow example correct - is my Dense parameter correct?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am following this [tutorial on image classification using TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-steps-to-build-your-first-image-classifier-with-code-cf244b015799).

I do need a bit of further explanation on certain parts.

The first question is, am I right in saying that the first Pickle `X` contains my images data, and the Pickle `y` contains the class names for my data?

How does the references in X tie up to references in Y?

My main question is the article says:

> In line 37, modify the parameter of Dense() to the number of classes
>   you have. This is the number of possible output by the neural network.

If I have 3 classes, should I change every `Dense()` to `Dense(3)`?

Does it mean change all references of:

```
model.add(Dense(x))
```

`model.add(Dense(x))` is written in 3 places in this code. Am I to change just the last entry of this? What does each one do?

---

As a conclusion, for 3 classes is the following code correct for the final layer?:

```
# The output layer with 3 neurons, for 3 classes
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Comment: If your model is a classifier and you have 3 classes, what you can do is add a Dense layer as an output layer with 3 nodes. Also you need to set its activation function to "softmax". If you do that, you will have as output of your model a vector of 3 components where the sum is equal to 1 and the k-th value will be the estimated probability of the input sample to be of the class k

Comment: No, you dont have to set the number of neurons on each dense layer to 3, only the output layer. You need to set also the loss function to be 'categorical_crossentropy' when compiling it (if you are using Keras)

Comment: Thanks Victor, I think I have it sorted now - can you confirm with my updated question? Also please post an answer concluding your comments so I can assign it the answer reward.

Comment: I also have the loss function set to : sparse_categorical_crossentropy -- is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

In your case, you should only set the amount of nodes to 3 in the dense output layer because you have 3 classes. 
For multi-class classification (with mutually exclusive classes) problems you typically need:

- Set the activation function of the output layer to softmax
- Change your loss function to `'categorical_crossentropy'` or `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` (when using Keras)

Note: 
The difference between both losses are the outputs. Categorical cross entropy returns for each sample a vector with the same size as your number of classes where the k-th value represents the probability of the sample to be of the class k 
In the other hand, the sparsed loss returns directly the predicted class as an integer label for each sample.

e.g:

```
[[0.5, 0.3, 0.2], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]] # Categorical
[0, 1]  # Sparsed
```